# How to apply tps rate on existing api endpoints at method level under apigatway in aws cdk

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm able to create UsagePlan and associate api stage using cdk, However struggling to define method throttling at api stage for specific resource path. I'm unable to get proper ref or solution on web.

Comment: Please add the (minimal) relevant CDK code to your question.

Comment: So you created apiGateway from CDK or it was already existing? If second, to get it you could use `RestApi.FromRestApiId`. And to add throttling, you'd just assign your throttling limits to `UsagePlan.throttle`

Answer (score 0):

Assign your throttling limits to `throttle` property of your UsagePlan, something like this:

```
const restApi: RestApi = myRestApi; // I assume you already have it since you managed to associate usage plan
const res = api.root.addResource('res');
const method = res.addMethod('GET');   
const methodThrottle:ThrottlingPerMethod = {
    method: method,
    throttle: {
        rateLimit:50,
        burstLimit:50
    }
}
const usagePlan =  new UsagePlan(this, "MyUsagePlan", {
    description: "UsagePlan for my API"，
    apiStages: [{
        api: restApi,
        stage: restApi.DeploymentStage,
        throttle: [ methodThrottle ] // that's per method
    }],
    throttle: maxThrottlingLimit, //that's max
});
```

Relevant example (honestly, shorter then mine):

- [UsagePlanPerApiStage official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.UsagePlanPerApiStage.html#throttle)